# Differences between 2 types of List patterns

Tags: f#

So, I am learning F# and been studying how lists are often used in pattern matching. I am saw 2 different List patterns and I am trying to figure out  the difference between them.

So lets say we are doing pattern matching on a list of chars like so

```
let charlist = ['x';'y';'z']
```

and we were matching it like so,

```
match charlist with
```

what would be difference between these 2 cases?

```
| [a;b;c] ->

| a::b::c::[] ->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, you can just ask the compiler:

```
> match charlist with           
- |[a;b;c] -> ()                
- |a::b::c::[] -> ()            
- | _ -> ();;                   

  |a::b::c::[] -> ()
  -^^^^^^^^^^^

/home/john/stdin(13,2): warning FS0026: This rule will never be matched
```

As the second rule is never matched, you know that it will only match when the first does, so that the second one is matches a subset of the first rule.  Reversing the order produces the same error message.  As a result, we know that they are identical.

Comment: Nice.  I would have asked the compiler by compiling both options to assemblies and then examining the IL.  This is much quicker and easier.